# apt-get install ubuntu-desktop; now what?

Tags: desktop-environment, lubuntu

I have lubuntu and I decided I actually want ubuntu. So, I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

as suggested [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/converting-between-the-ubuntus.5079/). It did its thing and now I apparently have ubuntu installed but I don't know how to boot into it.

[Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324831) it says that I can switch between them at the "greeter"? I don't know how to get to this.

Comment: The "greeter" is the graphical thing that asks you for your username/password—do you get one of those?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have the necessary setup and this ISN'T a server environment then you will have to reboot and you may see an option on the GRUB boot loader, or when you load the OS after boot loader. However, if this is a server environment you will have to install a vnc server `apt-get install tightvncserver` and then running `vncserver` then connect via an application such as realvnc viewer with `IPADDRESS:1`

Comment: WTF? There's no need to reboot (you aren't changing the kernel or the root filesystem), and VNC has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Yeah, should be a logout rather than a reboot but both would have the same result to be fair.

Comment: @Gilles Yet the OP marked it as the accepted answer so something tells me that it fixed his issue...

Also - IF he wanted to install ubuntu-desktop he'd have to reboot to load the new OS - i also said IF its a server environment (I don't know of Lubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Just log out and look for the LXDE or Lubuntu icon on the log-on screen.  There is a button that will bring down a list.  You should see a list of any desktop environments which you have installed.  Select Ubuntu or Unity, or however it is shown on the list and then log-in as normal.  :)